# angular TinyMCE integration

Tags: javascript, angular, tinymce, lazy-loading

I follow official doc for integrating `TinyMCE` with `Angular`: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/.

Now everything works fine, but `TinyMCE`s plugins loaded in application start, but I want it load asynchronously from `/src/assets/tinymce`. Question is,

> How can I load TinyMCE asynchronously when I need it?

*~ apologies for grammatical mistakes*

In `.angular-cli.json` I have `scripts` array:

```
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/table/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/image/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/imagepicker/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/imagetools/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/advlist/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/autolink/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/lists/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/charmap/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/print/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/preview/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/hr/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/anchor/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/pagebreak/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/searchreplace/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/wordcount/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/visualblocks/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/visualchars/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/fullscreen/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/insertdatetime/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/media/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/nonbreaking/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/save/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/contextmenu/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/directionality/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/template/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/textcolor/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/colorpicker/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/textpattern/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/toc/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/code/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/autoresize/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/help/plugin.js"
      ],
```

these scripts are plugins of `TinyMCE`

Comment: You can decide when you call the `tinymce.init()` method to initialize it. In their docs it is called from angular after the view initializes where in reality you can create your own event listener and then call that event when needed. Look into [`EventEmmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) for accomplishing just that.

Comment: @MattNewelski: Currently I installed `tinymce` and it located under `node_modules`, but I want it in `/src/assets` and then load it when I need it )

Comment: then dont install it. Just download the js and css files and save them in assets folder and load the script on demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare these 2 on top in your component:

```
declare var tinymce: any;
const url = '//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js';
```

Use this function to load the script in your component's onInit function:

```
loadScript() {
    let scriptTag = document.querySelector('script[src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"]');
    let node;
    if (!scriptTag) {
      node = document.createElement('script');
      node.src = url;
      node.type = 'text/javascript';
      node.async = true;
      node.charset = 'utf-8';
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
    }
  }
```

and then use the following function to load the tinymce:

```
loadTinyMCE() {
    if (tinymce)
      tinymce.init({
        selector: '#tinymce',
        skin_url: 'assets/skins/lightgray',
        plugins: ['paste', 'link', 'autoresize','image'],
        setup: editor => {
          this.editor = editor;
        }
      })
  }
```

and finally destroy the tinymce object on ngdestroy:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    tinymce.remove();
  }
```

It might be the bad approach but it saves me from loading the script on application load and gives me the ability to load it only when it is needed.

Comment: imho currently the best way to include scripts dynamically